# Calculate simple hours in MS Excel

Tags: excel

How to calculate hours between 2 columns in MS Excel?
Sample data is: `04 Jan 2021  6:00:00:000PM` and `04 Jan 2021  9:06:00:000AM`

Comment: Have you tried the difference? Like in cell C1 "=B1-A1" ?

Comment: Subtraction usually works well, once you understand that Excel stores date/times as days and fractions of a day since `1-Jan-1900`, and format your results accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you!
As a first step, I formatting the cells containing the date and time to mm/dd/yy h:mm.
Then I calculate the number of hours by converting the output to text "TEXT(J2-I2,"h")"